# Mini DisplayPort 1.2 to DP 1.2 on Dell monitor not working

Tags: display, intel-graphics, displayport, mesa

I have a laptop (TUXEDO Book BC1510) with 1 HDMI and 1 Mini DisplayPort 1.2 running Pop!_OS 20.04. Pop is an Ubuntu derived distro by System76.

This is in "About":

- i7 9750H
- Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)

I'm running a setup where I use three screens, where one of them is the built-in screen, one HDMI, and one DP. I tried daisy chaining, but DP was incredibly unreliable and still is when not chaining.

The issue specifically is that the monitor is always in a power save state and never wakes. I've managed back in 18.04 to have it *kind of* work, usually after at least 2~3 reboots; DP screen would usually work for about 5 to 6 hours, and then enter the power save state.

I'm getting tired of having to try various rip-off "solutions", so I want a proper "don't have to reboot multiple times every morning and again in the afternoon" solutions. I could of course buy a USB-C to HDMI adapter, but that's not a proper solution, much more a workaround.

I'm running X11. Changing to Wayland does not change anything.

`xrandr --listmonitors` just to show that all monitors are being detected:

```bsh
Monitors: 3
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/344x1080/194+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +HDMI-2 1920/518x1200/324+3840+0  HDMI-2
 2: +DP-1-8 1920/518x1200/324+1920+0  DP-1-8
```

`uname -a`:

```bsh
Linux pop-os 5.4.0-7642-generic #46~1598628707~20.04~040157c-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 28 18:02:16 UTC  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"`:

```bsh
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
```

I'm happy to bring any necessary information.

Thanks in advance.